# 2.9 is 14.5 in a score of 20 for the given 4 entries is it correct

Tags: javascript, java, math, percentage, aptitude

For example number of working days is 4,

```
7/10=0.7
8/10=0.8
9/10=0.9
5/10=0.5
Total is:

Total =.7+.8+.9+.5=2.9
```

How can I calculate this total (2.9) as a percentage of the total (20)?

Is my attempt correct below:

```
Computed to 20% = (sum of values for four days)%(number of working days)*20
```

= (2.9)%4*20
= 14.5

Comment: JavaScript or Java? And also, what do you mean by convert to 20%?

Comment: It should be math, any language not a problem

Comment: the sum of values i need to convert to 20% (.7+.8+.9+.5=2.9).

Comment: ut what do you mean by 20%? What is your expected output? Do you want `.7 + .8 + .9 + .5` to result in `29%`, or `20%`, or something else?

Comment: OK, the sum is (2.9), I need to convert to 20%.

Comment: This is still quite unclear. You can't convert 2.9 to 20%, that doesn't make sense. Is there a language barrier? Are you looking to get 20% of your total sum just? Or something else?

Comment: U mean you need 20% of 2.9 ?

Comment: yes Can u guide me

Comment: 2.9 / 5 ? or 2.9 * 20% etc?

Comment: @notyou. 2.9 * 20% (we need to get score out of 20 based on 2.9(four entries))

Comment: So you've four entries, which total 2.9, and you want to know what percentage, out of a total of 20, which that equates to? (2.9 * 100 / 20 *or* 2.9 * 5)?

Comment: Yes Exactly.@notyou

Comment: Then just multiply by 100 and divide by the total (20). Or in this case, just multiply by 5. You also have this in your example ((2.9)%4*20 = 14.5) which yields the same result.

Answer (score 1):

By reading the discussion, I think @ramu, what you have given is correct. Yes 2.9 is 14.5 in a score of 20 for the given 4 entries.

You would need to multiply `2.9 * 5 = 14.5` which is out of `20`. This is correct.

Comment: Thanks you .how you got 5?  Tell me i will mark as answer

Comment: You have 4 entries and their maximum value sums up to 4. Since you ideally want this 4 to be 20. Thus you need to multiply 4 by 5 to get the 20. Similarly your answer should be multiplied by 5 which will get you 14.5.

Comment: I have one issue, we have 35 entries what u will do?

Comment: So your maximum value sums up to 35 in the case of 35 entries. Which means 35 is equivalent to 20. There for you need to multiply your obtained result by `20/35` or `4/7`. Therefore: `result x 4/7` will be out of 20

Answer (score 1):

Your total is `2.9`. As (sort-of) explained in the comments, you want to know what percentage of the overall total (20 in your example) is.

You can either:

- Multiply (2.9) by 100 and divide by your total (20) - giving 14.5%
- Or just in this use-case, multiply (2.9) by 5.

Answer (score -3):

To calculate the percentage, `totalvalue/100*percentagevalue` i.e, `30/100*20` calculates to `20%` of `30`.

```js
var a=7,b=8,c=9,d=5;
var values = a/10+b/10+c/10+d/10;
var percentage = values/100*20;
console.log("Total : "+(a+b+c+d),"Values : "+values,"Percentage : "+percentage.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: is it possible to covert 20% of (var values = a/10+b/10+c/10+d/10;
)

Comment: @ramu I think this is what you needed.

Comment: I think @ramu you mean, you need 20% of your result?

Comment: 2.9 * 20% (we need to get score out of 20. based on 2.9(four entries))

Comment: @raja , We need to get value out of 20. from the four values(2.9)